# HiPi (Raspberry Pi library) fails with undef subroutine HiPi::GPIO::xs_gpio_*

Tags: perl, raspberry-pi, gpio, hipi

Whatever function to control a GPIO pin with module HiPi / HiPi::GPIO I try - it always fails with

`Undefined subroutine &HiPi::GPIO::xs_gpio_write called at /usr/local/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/perl/5.36.0/HiPi/GPIO.pm line 66.`

(for example). The exact subroutine depends on whoch function I call, it is always `xs_gpio_something`.

**Environment:**

- Raspbian (Debian 12 Bookworm Lite, not graphical environment)
- Perl 5.36.1
- HiPi 0.90 installed as per instructions on their website *
- Raspberry Pi 4 Model B Rev 1.5, 2 GB

**Simplest code to reproduce**

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use v5.36;

use HiPi qw( :rpi );
use HiPi::GPIO;

my $gpio = HiPi::GPIO->new();
$gpio->set_pin_level( RPI_PIN_15, RPI_HIGH );
```

* HiPi installation instructions
https://hipi.znix.com/install.html

Any ideas?

TIA,
Ekki

Already tried:

- compiling my own HiPi in a local Perl (with perlbrew), no joy.
- using HiPi::GPIO::Pin as alternative, same results
- looking for answers elsewhere, nothing

Comment: `xs_gpio_write` is a C function defined in `CPIO.xs`.  Did you do a complete build, and did that build successfully compile all the `.xs` files?

Comment: I did a complete build.

Meanwhile I found the root cause for the issue.

HiPi::RaspberryPi checks for the hardware and model by looking at the output of /proc/cpuinfo. For unknown reasons my board does not output a certain line ('Hardware') which is expected by HiPi::RaspberryPi.

Further, the result of function is_raspberry() relies on this information. Most prominently: the loading of XS modules with XSloader depends on this information. The CPIO.xs extension issimply not loaded, and therefore fails each time I try to call a function there.

Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 2):

The solution is to use HiPi vrsion 0.91 and later to fix this.

The author of HiPi found that the culprit is an unanticipated change in the format of /proc/cpuinfo. This is now resolved, the fix is available from HiPi 0.91 on. XSLoader now works as expected. Thanks, Mark.